# What exactly does it mean to "resolve" a path?

Tags: java, path, resolver

I've now read numerous articles on the use of Java `somePath.resolve( someOtherPath )` but I can't find a precise definition, with helpful examples, of what *exactly* "resolving" a Path means. Everyone seems to assume you know.
Can someone define it non-circularly? Or point me to a (non-circular) explainer?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `Path`?

Comment: *"Everyone seems to assume you know"* Because everyone assumes you've read the **documentation**.

Comment: How about this: A`.resolve(`B`)` means "yield the path you could use to get to the same location as starting with A and continuing with B".

Comment: It sounds like you are saying it simply means "append" but that's not the sense I get from the docs. In some cases, yes. And why not just say "append"?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is defined in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.lang.String)), which does a great job of indicating what the method does.

> Converts a given path string to a Path and resolves it against this Path in exactly the manner specified by the resolve method. For example, suppose that the name separator is "/" and a path represents "foo/bar", then invoking this method with the path string "gus" will result in the Path "foo/bar/gus".

In other words, if the path `C:/Program Files/Foo/` is the current `Path` and `Bar` exists in `Foo`, you could do the following:

```java
Path parent = Paths.get("C:", "Program Files", "Foo");

Path child = parent.resolve("Bar");
```

Comment: Another circular definition that uses "resolve" to define "resolve".

Comment: The documentation says that if the string can't be converted to a path, then it throws an InvalidPathException.  But under what circumstances can something not be converted?  In this example, if Bar does not exist, does resolving it fail?  Or does it create a Bar file?  Or does it just return a path that points at a theoretical Bar file or directory that I would have to make real with another call?

Comment: That is a good question Tim. Path relies on FileSystem which is dependent on the OS, so the behaviour would depend on the OS (I presume). I don't believe Path is responsible for file or directory creation, but I could be wrong. That would be up to something like `Files#write(Path)` where if Bar didn't exist, it would create bar, based on potentially the `OpenOption`'s provided. I apologize if this wasn't helpful, took a quick glance at the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Jason's answer is complete, but on the off chance you're looking for an even simpler answer/example..

I would say the "resolve" method that you specificaly referred to (which starts at somePath) starts at a certain Path, somePath, and then tells you what would happen if you choose to go to someOtherPath but specifically starting at somePath.

So if you had a directory structure on a PC, for example, like this:

```
C:
 - FolderA
   - Folder1
 - FolderB
   - Folder1
```

If you resolved someOtherPath as "Folder1", then it would depend where you started...

- If your somePath was "/FolderA" then you'd end up at "C:/FolderA/Folder1"
- If your somePath was "/FolderB" then you'd end up at "C:/FolderB/Folder1"
- If your somePath was "/" (the root), then you'd have an invalid path...